# How to use PgSearch's multisearch_options to set the stemming dictionary language from the model instance's language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg-search

With PgSearch, I'd like to make use of the stemming dictionaries for full text search in multisearch (database is Postgres 15).

On my model, I have:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch::Model
  PgSearch.multisearch_options = {
    ignoring: :accents,
    using: {
      tsearch: { dictionary: 'english' }
    }
  }
  multisearchable against: %i[my_column my_other_column]
end
```

Unfortunately, the text I want to run the multisearch on can be in a variety of languages. Each model has a `language` column that specifies what language it's in, but I don't know how to use it with `.multiserach_options` because at the time that code runs, I only have the class and not an instance of it.

So I can't do:

```
# ...
      tsearch: { dictionary: language } #=> NoMethodError `language'
# ...
```

I tried this:

```rb
PgSearch.multisearch_options = ->(record) {
  {
    ignoring: :accents,
    using: {
      tsearch: { dictionary: record.language }
  }
}
```

but that didn't work, as it doesn't seem to accept/run the lambda.

How can I dynamically define the dictionary's language for each record?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out, kinda.

First of all, the `PgSearch.multisearch_options = ...` needs to go in an initializer. I put it in `config/initializers/pg_search.rb`.

Second, it doesn't really make sense to set the dictionary per model instance because the multisearch is executed across all of them. So since I have documents in multiple languages, I guess I can only use the `simple` dictionary.